# Datatable as a cell of another datatable in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there any methode to return a data table as a particular cell of another datatable.
Ie, I hav a datatable with 3 columns. the second column contains multiple values for a single record.... If there any methode to attain this through a single table....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having multiple values in a single cell is contrary to even the **First Normal Form** of database design. Don't do it - it will only cause you grief....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have a table as a column. You can have a XML column to store structured information. XML columns can also be queried.

More info about xml data type can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190936%28v=sql.90%29.aspx.

Example of what you can do with xml.

```
declare @T table (id int, data xml)

insert into @T values (1, '<root><val1>1</val1><val2>2</val2></root>')
insert into @T values (2, '<root><val1>11</val1><val2>12</val2></root>')

select
  id,
  r.r.value('val1[1]', 'int') as Val1,
  r.r.value('val2[1]', 'int') as Val2
from @T
  cross apply
    data.nodes('root') r(r)
```

Result

```
id Val1 Val2
1  1    2
2  11   12
```

Comment: Thanks mikael... If you dnt mind please refer me an example or any URL.